# PHP Image Caching

Tags: php, caching

I am having a problem with [php image caching](https://nielse63.github.io/php-image-cache/). I have already posted this on the authors issue page, however it isn't active.

**Web server:**  NGINX

**PHP Version:** 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.14

I am getting this error *Final image URL is broken*. The page looks like this
[image: page]
There should be 100 images displayed but it dies at the third.
The page should look something similar to this (this is the localhost design)
[image: Design of Page]

It is returning this URL
[image: exampleImage]

There should be a `/` between the `mediapage.zips.me` and `core`, however it is a local image so I don't see why it should even need the host name.

How I am doing this is,

On the top of each page I am calling another page which contains the setup of the class

```
<?php
    //Calls the php-image things
    include 'test.php';

?>
```

Inside test.php

```
<?php 
    require_once 'core/classes/ImageCache.php';
    $imagecache = new ImageCache();
?>
```

Image page

```
<?php 
    //Directory NON-CACHED images are stored in
    $dir    =   "i/";

    //Array of files in the Directory
    $files1 =   scandir($dir);
    //Used to limit results (100's of images)
    $count = 0;
    foreach ($files1 as $key) {
        //If the file name is longer than 3 chars and the count is less 
        //than the amount of images I want displayed.
        if (strlen($key) > 3 && $count <= 100){
            $count++;
            //dir2 is the directory/nameofFile.extension
            //Eg: i/testImage.png
            $dir2   =   $dir.''.$key;
            $info = new SplFileInfo($key);
            //Image Cache variable
            $cached_src = $imagecache->cache($dir2);
?>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <!-- Link for light box for full resolution image -->
            <a href="<?php echo $dir2;?>" data-popup="lightbox">
                <!-- src of cached image is outputted and the alt is the name of the uncached image. -->
                <img src="<?php echo $cached_src;?>" alt="<?php echo $key;?>" class="img-rounded img-preview">
            </a>
        </td>
        <!-- More table stuff... -->
    </tr>

<?php
        } //End If
    } //End for
?>
```

I have tried adding a `/` to the directory name `$dir` but it says that it cant find the directory when I do that.

Comment: I'm guessing that $dir2 is a filesystem directory, that's why you can't just add a slash to it. That would just put it at a root directory which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

```
        <!-- Link for light box for full resolution image -->
        <a href="<?php echo $dir2; ?>" data-popup="lightbox">
            <!-- src of cached image is outputted and the alt is the name of the uncached image. -->
            <img src="/<?php echo $cached_src; ?>" alt="<?php echo $key; ?>" class="img-rounded img-preview">
        </a>
```

This should work by simpling prepending a slash before the `$cached_src`.

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at [ImageCache github page](https://github.com/nielse63/php-image-cache/blob/master/src/ImageCache/ImageCache.php#L284) for reference.  If the cached image doesn't exist yet, the script will use `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`. So verify what is in that. It looks like if your `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` doesn't end with a slash, then your url won't have one.